# How do I restrict specific IP ranges from viewing a specific page in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to only allow specific IP ranges to access /user/login. Denying anything under the /user sub-directory would suffice.

So far I've tried:

```
<Location /user>
    Order deny,allow  
    Deny from all
    Allow from 123.45.116.0/24
    Allow from 123.225.232.0/23
    Allow from 123.225.114.0/23
    Allow from 123.9.53
</Location>
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.116\.0/24$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.225\.232\.0/23$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.225\.114\.0/23$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.9\.534$
RewriteRule ^user/? - [F,NC]
```

and

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^123\.45\.116\.0/24
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^123\.225\.232\.0/23
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^123\.225\.114\.0/23
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^123\.9\.53\.
 RewriteRule ^(user|user/login) - [F]
```

no luck. Could anyone out there please help? I always struggle with htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are looking to allow specific IP ranges(taken from your efforts) and URI should start from `user` then you may try following. So in case IP addresses doesn't come in mentioned IP ranges and its trying to hit URL like `http://lcoalhost:80/user`(as an example) then it will Forbid that page. Here is [Online demo for regex used](https://regex101.com/r/VGFE9R/1)

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.116\.([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-4])$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.225\.232\.([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.225\.114\.([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.9\.53
RewriteRule ^user/? - [F,NC,L]
```

Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

---

---

OR you could use a single condition also, use either above OR following only at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !(^123\.45\.116\.([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-4])$)|(^123\.225\.232\.([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])$)|(^123\.225\.114\.([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])$)|(^123\.9\.53)
RewriteRule ^user/? - [F,NC,L]
```